# Serving Multi-Page Dash App with Flask and User Login

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash, dashboard

I am trying to build a multi-page dashboard with python dash and flask while serving the dashboard only to logged in users. The issue I am facing is, that even though I have defined the routes in the flask server, the dash seems to overrule them and thus ignoring the user authentication.
When I run the `flask_app.py`  I can directly access `http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/` without the need to login, also I don't see the '!' being printed to the terminal which I defined in the route as debug message. So I assume, that somehow not the flask route is active but the dashboard behind.
My project structure is:

```
myapp/
|-- __init__.py
|-- flask_app.py
|-- dash_app
    |-- pages/
        |-- __init__.py
        |-- home.py
        |-- cities.py
    |-- templates/
        |-- login.html
```

`flask_app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, session, request
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_user, login_required, logout_user, current_user
from flask_session import Session
from dash_app import initDash

flask_app = Flask(__name__)
flask_app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'your_secret_key'
flask_app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'

# Initialize Flask-Login
login_manager = LoginManager(flask_app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'

# Mock user class for demonstration purposes
class User(UserMixin):
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

# Simulating user authentication
users = {'abc': {'password': 'abc'}}

dash_app_loc = initDash(flask_app)

# Flask routes
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User(user_id)

@flask_app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.form.get('username')
            password = request.form.get('password')

            user = users.get(username)
            if user and user['password'] == password:
                user_obj = User(username)
                login_user(user_obj)
                return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))

        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    
@flask_app.route('/login/', methods=['GET'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
    else:
        return render_template('login.html')

@flask_app.route('/login/', methods=['POST'])
def login_post():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))

    # Handling the login logic for POST requests
    username = request.form.get('username')
    password = request.form.get('password')

    user = users.get(username)
    if user and user['password'] == password:
        user_obj = User(username)
        login_user(user_obj)
        return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))

    return redirect(url_for('login'))

@flask_app.route('/logout/')
@login_required
def logout():
    print('!')
    logout_user()
    session.clear()
    return redirect(url_for('login'))

@flask_app.route('/dashboard/')
@login_required
def dashboard():
    print('!')
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return dash_app_loc
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))

# Handle 404 errors by redirecting to the login page
@flask_app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return redirect(url_for('login'))

# Initialize Flask-Session
Session(flask_app)

# Run the Flask app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    flask_app.run(debug=True, port=8000)
```

`dash_app.py`:

```
import dash
from dash import Dash, html, dcc


def initDash(server):
    dash_app = Dash(__name__, server=server, url_base_pathname='/dashboard/', use_pages=True)
    # dash_app = Dash(__name__, server=server, use_pages=True)
    
    dash_app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('Multi-page app with Dash Pages'),
    html.Div([
        html.Div(
            dcc.Link(f"{page['name']} - {page['path']}", href=page["relative_path"])
        ) for page in dash.page_registry.values()
    ]),
    dash.page_container
])
    
    return dash_app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    initDash(True).run_server(debug=True)
```

`home.py`:

```
import dash
from dash import html


dash.register_page(__name__, path='/')

layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('This is our first page!!!')
])
```

`cities.py`:

```
import dash
from dash import html, dcc, callback, Input, Output


dash.register_page(__name__)

layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('This is our city page'),
    html.Div([
        "Select a city: ",
        dcc.RadioItems(
            options=['New York City', 'Montreal', 'San Francisco'],
            value='Montreal',
            id='analytics-input'
        )
    ]),
    html.Br(),
    html.Div(id='analytics-output'),
])


@callback(
    Output('analytics-output', 'children'),
    Input('analytics-input', 'value')
)
def update_city_selected(input_value):
    return f'You selected: {input_value}'
```

`login.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('login_post') }}">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
        <br>
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the terminal output, I also don't understand why accessng the dashboard fires 4 GET requests? The marked part is where I would expect a '!', if the flask route is working correctly.
[terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UPCl.png)

EDIT: Forgot the `login.html`.

I expected that the flask route is bein taken but somehow the dash is overruling it. I tried to adapt the `url_base_pathname='/dashboard/'` but had no luck with it.

UPDATE: Upon replacing the return of the flask route of /dashboard/ to a simple string like 'a', the pages/routes/logins are working as expected. Since dash is also running on flask it seems obvious to me, that there is a conflict of my flask server and the internal handling of the dash-flask. However I am not sure on where my mistake is. Is there any other option than to give the flask_app to the server argument of the dash?